# Firebase & Flask - "The default Firebase app already exists". But why?

Tags: firebase, flask

I'm getting this error when I try and initialize Firebase in my Flask app.

```
ValueError: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initialize_app() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initialize_app() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initialize_app() to give each app a unique name.
```

I understand what the error means, but I can't understand why I get it on the second call to the API. My Flask code is as follows:

```
@app.route("/lla/newchat",methods = ['GET'])
def newchat():
        bot.firebasekey = json.loads(utils.getSecret("firebase-key"))
        bot.databaseURL ='https://xxxx.firebaseio.com'
        bot.databaseAuthVariableOverride='my-service-worker'
        bot.initialiseChat()
        db=bot.getDbCon()

        return "ok"

def getDbCon(self):
        cred = credentials.Certificate(self.firebasekey)
        if not firebase_admin._apps:
            firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
            'databaseURL': self.databaseURL,
            'databaseAuthVariableOverride': {'uid': self.databaseAuthVariableOverride}})
        db = firestore.client()
        return db
```

If I call this API once, it seems to process correctly. But if I call the API a second time it gives me the above error.
I would have thought that 'db' is disposed of by flask once the api finishes the first time round, but somehow it remembers 'db' when I call it a second time? Is that right?

Edit:

I've since inserted the `if not firebase_admin._apps:` that you see above which rectifies my problem but I am trying to understand how Firebase works. Does the error refer to something on the Firebase side?